# Is there any reason to write $y^{(n)}=\dfrac{d^ny}{dx^n}$ rather than $y^{(n)}=\dfrac{d^ny}{d^nx}$?

Tags: derivatives, notation

For the function $y(x)$ we have $y'=\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ , $y''=\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ , $y'''=\dfrac{d^3y} {dx^3}$ and in general $y^{(n)}=\dfrac{d^ny}{dx^n}$. I'm wondering is there any explanation that why we write $y^{(n)}=\dfrac{d^ny}{dx^n}$ rather than $y^{(n)}=\dfrac{d^ny}{d^nx}$? Or it is the matter of notation and we should accept it without reasoning?